# Find f(z) where Z= X+Y

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{8}$ for $-2<x<2$ and $0<y<2$. Find $f(z)$ where $Z = X+Y.$

Should I find the marginal of X and Y first, then $$f(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(z-x)dx ?$$

Comment: You need to be careful to make limits of integration match the support of the joint distribution $f_{X,Y}(x,y).$

Answer (score 1):

Because the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is uniform on
its support [the rectangle with vertices at $(-2,0)$ and $(2,2)$],
it is not difficult find the CDF of $T = X + Y$ directly.

See the figure below: *Upper left:* Points illustrate the
uniform distribution of $(X, Y)$ in the supporting rectangle.
*Upper right;* Modified to illustrate that $P(T < 1) = 1/2.$
Other values of $F_T(t) = P(T \le t)$ can be found similarly;
there are three cases for $t$. *Lower left:* A histogram of a million
simulated realizations of $T$ suggests that the PDF of $T$
consists of three linear pieces---for $(-2,0),\,(0,2),$ and $(2,4),$ respectively. *Lower right:* The empirical
CDF of $T$ suggests the form of the CDF.

[image]

Comment: Drawings are nice and may help to support the intuition, yes, but why not add the analytical form of $f_T$?

Comment: Building intuition, giving hints, not completed answers.

Answer (score 0):

$$F_Z(z) = P(X+Y \leq z) = \iint_{x+y \leq z} f_{XY}(x,y)\text{dxdy} = \iint_{x+y \leq z} \frac{1}{8}\text{dxdy}$$

You only need to figure out the integration limits and then

$$f_Z(z) = \frac{d}{dz}F_Z(z)$$